# Why won't my \otoprule command work in table formatting?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, booktabs

Primer: I'm very new to LaTeX. I am creating a `table` with the following code. Here is part of the table:

```
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, booktabs}
\begin{table}[tp]
\caption{Rain garden site characteristics}
\label{table:11}
\begin{tabular}{c r @{.} l c r @{.} l r @{.} l r @{.} l r @{.} l}
Site ID &   Surface Area        &   Install Date    &   Roof Catchment Area &   Total Cactchment Area   &   $A_garden$/$A_imper$    &   $A_garden$/$A_total$    \\\otoprule
1   &   10&2    &   2007    &   49&7    &   49&7    &   20&6    &   20&6        \\\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why it has a problem with `\otoprule`. I've seen it in many [table style guides](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mori/mori.pdf), and can't figure out what I'm missing. The error code I get is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \otoprule
1.5 ... A_imp$ & $A_garden$/$A_total$ \\\otoprule
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: It is `\toprule`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too. But if you look at page 3 of the PDF I linked in the question, you'll see `\otoprule%`. What do you make of that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5):

In the cited source`\otoprule` is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}
```

So you should add the preceeding line to obtain the desired result.

Comment: Could you enlighten me as to what that command does? Is it overriding the thickness of `toprule`?

Comment: No, it produces some rule of defined thickness.

Answer (score 3):

The required definition that you're missing is given in the [document](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mori/mori.pdf) (p 10):

> In this article the line below the heading of the tables has always thickness equal
>   to `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` but it is vertically centered with respect to the row
>   above and below (which is typical of the lines `\midrule`). To obtain this result, a
>   new line type has been deﬁned with the following command
>
> ```
> \newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}
> ```

The definition of `\midrule` from [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) resembles:

```
\def\midrule{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
  \@aboverulesep=\aboverulesep
  \global\@belowrulesep=\belowrulesep
  \global\@thisruleclass=\@ne
  \@ifnextchar[{\@BTrule}{\@BTrule[\lightrulewidth]}}
```

This definition sets the separation above and below the impending horizontal rule to be equal-ish (`\belowrulesep=.65ex` and `aboverulesep=.4ex`). It also allows for the optional specification of the rule thickness. `\midrule` alone defaults to `\@BTrule[\lightrulewidth]`, although you can otherwise specific the rule width in the optional argument; exactly what `\otoprule` does through it's definition as `\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]`. `\heavyrulewidth` is the length definition used to shape the thickness of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`, as mentioned in the article:

```
\def\toprule{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
  \@aboverulesep=\abovetopsep
  \global\@belowrulesep=\belowrulesep %global cos for use in the next noalign
  \global\@thisruleclass=\@ne
  \@ifnextchar[{\@BTrule}{\@BTrule[\heavyrulewidth]}}
\def\bottomrule{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
  \@aboverulesep=\aboverulesep
  \global\@belowrulesep=\belowbottomsep
  \global\@thisruleclass=\@ne
  \@ifnextchar[{\@BTrule}{\@BTrule[\heavyrulewidth]}}
```